# AngularJS Unit Testing a Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having some trouble, unit testing a simple User Service that has exposes two functions. 
The test and the service are given below. 
Whenever i run the tests, I keep getting the following error..

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) User Service should contain a UserService FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserProvider <- User
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=UserProvider%20%3C-%20User (line 4501)
```

The Service

```
angular.module('y2yApp').service('User', function($http) {

    this.profile = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: config.MW_URL + '/profile'
        }).then(function(response) {
            return {
                err: null,
                data: response.data
            };
        }, function(response) {
            return {
                err: response.data,
                data: null
            };
        });
    };

    this.update = function(userInfo) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: config.MW_URL + '/profile',
            data : userInfo
        });
    };
});
```

The Test

```
describe('User Service', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.module('y2yApp');

    });
    it('should contain a UserService',inject(['User',function(User) {
        console.log(User);
            expect(User).not.to.equal(null);
    }]));



});
```

If this one test runs, and I am able to get the User service instance correctly, I can go ahead and write the rest of the tests, but for some reason its not working. Can someone please help me regarding this and shed some light on what I am doing wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

This [should be](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)

```
module('y2yApp');
```

Which is CommonJS-unsafe shortcut for

```
angular.mock.module('y2yApp');
```

Comment: This is the error in the code you've posted. The reason why it is not passing may be Karma configuration or anything else that stays behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, there was a mistake in my app initialisation